# Is it possible to get products in the shopping cart using Magento API?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, api

I've already written custom payment gateway for example.
How can I get products properties in the shopping cart, when customer reaches payment details page (before he redirect to the bank page as final step of this procedure)? Is it possible to get products information with Magento API in simple "home-made" php application for further use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `shoppingCartInfo` method, as long as you pass the quote ID as a parameter.

Here is more information (and some examples at the bottom):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html

In your case, you would be interested in the `shoppingCartItemEntity` object it returns.

Comment: Thanks!
It looks like a solution of my issue.
I'll accept you answer after I test this method.